# Do Always Connected PCs with ARM processors (e.g. HP Envy x2) allow to run non-Windows-Store executables compiled for ARM?

Tags: compile, microsoft-surface, arm, windows-rt, hp-envy

FFMPEG and Audacity, which were compiled for jailbroken Windows RT before, are relatively CPU-intensive, so I'd assume they'd drain the battery less if compiled for ARM on one of the upcoming Windows 10 ARM PCs. I know that ordinary x86 32-bit executables are supported besides Windows Store apps, but what about ordinary ARM executables?

Comment: ARM is a low power CPU design, not a magically more efficient (therefore lower power) program format. To run ARM executables would require emulation of the ARM CPU which would be **more** work, not less.

Comment: I am referring to upcoming Snapdragon-powered PCs running Windows 10, like the HP Envy x2 and the ASUS NovaGo and have updated my question to make that clearer.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. For reference a Surface Pro claims to be "always connected" in various bits of blurb and runs on x86 processors. Using proper descriptions always trumps vague and fuzzy marketing terms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, and you are asking if you can use FFMPEG and Audacity ARM binaries on ordinary Windows to save cpu power, the answer is no -

I don't believe ARM executables can be executed in x86 Windows , but even if they could it would be slower because of the emulation envolved.

Also, the ARM binaries probably use less power because they are optimised for ARM, not X86.

Comment: I am referring to upcoming Snapdragon-powered PCs running Windows 10, like the HP Envy x2 and the ASUS NovaGo and have updated my question to make that clearer, sorry.